# Polling server for new chat messages periodically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a basic chat system implemented, using Rails. I am using a Message model for this, and I'm polling the server for new messages every X seconds. When the user opens the chat page, all the messages will have been rendered to the view. I am also starting the polling "job" like this:

```
if($("#chat").length > 0) {
    $.periodic({period: 5000, decay: 1.2, max_period: 60000}, function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: document.location.href,
            dataType: 'script'
        });
    });
}
```

My controller looks like this:

```
def index
    @messages = Message.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.js
    end
end
```

`index.js.erb` looks like this:

```
$("#chat li").remove();
<% @messages.each do |msg| %>
 $("#chat").append("<li>" + "<%= escape_javascript msg.content %>" + "</li>");
<% end %>
```

Is it ok the way I have it now or should I be returning JSON and process it in the polling job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `Model.all` is a big red flag. What if there are thousands or millions of records defined? You're going to fetch them *all*.

What you should be doing is passing in a parameter on the update of the last ID you fetched, then scoping your messages accordingly. It might be more reasonable to follow this pattern:

```
def index
  scope = Message

  if (params[:id])
    # Only fetch those messages created after the last update
    scope = scope.where('id > ?', params[:id])
  end

  # Fetch the 100 most recent messages
  @messages = scope.limit(100).order('created_at DESC').all
end
```

If you track the maximum ID number on the client side, you can pass this parameter in for the subsequent fetch.

Since you're only fetching new records, you should append these to your list, not replace your list entirely.

Comment: How/where would I store the last id, since I am fetching so many at once? In the session?

Comment: Usually the last ID retrieved is stored in your client-side JavaScript as a persistent variable bound to something convenient.

Comment: Can you give an example to this storing? I don't understand what you mean by bounding it to something convenient.

Comment: All I mean is to store it in a JavaScript variable on the client so that between each fetch request you know where to pick up. JavaScript variables can persist as long as the page is being shown.